# SCSS Mixin for CSS Animation

Tags: sass, css-animations, scss-mixins

I am trying to create a SCSS mixin as all of my animated elements share the same settings except for the `animation-name`

```
$animationDuration: 2s;
$animationTimingFunction: linear;
$animationIterationCount: infinite;
$animationDirection: alternate;

@mixin shapeAnimation($name) {
    animation: $name $animationDuration $animationTimingFunction $animationIterationCount $animationDirection;
}
```

When I call the mixin `@include shapeAnimation(shape1)` the animation does not run, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: @yousoumar shape1 is the name of the animation keyframe name

Comment: Seems ok. Is the `@keyframes` defined?